# Unlocked packages: Lightning Aura Component Inheritance issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inheritance, unlocked-package

I have two namespaced unlocked packages, an aura component from one package extends a component from another one.

There is a component within the base component with aura:id="cmpId" (It's a global component). Save method tries to find it.
On the base component there is a 'save' button which works fine when you press it from your extension. But if you try to use the same method from the base components helper class, for instance create a new button on your extension which will call the same save method - it doesn't work.

I tried to debug the issue and I found out that component.find('cmpId') doesn't find anything in the second case

Has anyone had similar issue?

Regards,

Artem